# Reversing string in python using def

Tags: python, string, function, reverse

Can anyone help me with the assignment - I have to reverse a string by using def. I am not allowed to use approaches like [::-1] or .reversed...
The following function works, but prints vertically:

```
def ex1(name):    
    for x in range(len(name)-1,-1,-1):
        print(name[x])

k
r
o
Y

w
e
N
```

how do I put the letters back into horizontal order?? Anyone? Thanks!

Comment: You need to show what you've tried before you ask for help (or your question will get closed).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like so:

```
>>> def ex1(name):
...     return "".join([name[x] for x in range(len(name)-1,-1,-1)])
...
>>> print(ex1('abcd'))
dcba
>>>
```

Also, notice that I made the function *return* the string instead of print it.  If your teachers want you to use `def` for this job, then they probably want that too.  If not, then you can always replace `return` with `print` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close:

```
def ex1(name):
    reverseName=""
    for x in range(len(name)-1,-1,-1):
        reverseName+=name[x]
    print reverseName
```

The `print` statement prints a newline character (a line break) after each line, this is why you get your characters in vertical. The solution is not to print the character in each loop, but to collect them in a string and print the final string at once at the end.

Note that there are more efficient ways of doing this (see the other answers), but it might be the most straightforward way and the closest one to what you have already done.

Comment: I believe on some platforms and not others, += of strings in a loop is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way that you can reverse a string.

```
def ex1(name):
    length = len(name)
    return "".join([name[length-x-1] for x in range(0, length)])

print ex1("hello world")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name=input("Whats your name ?")

def reversemyname(name):
    x=name[::-1]
    return x
reversedname=reversemyname(name)
print(reversedname)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
print(name[x]), # <= add that comma
```

if you want the output like this `kroy wen` then try this:

```
sys.stdout.write(name[x])
```

remember to `import sys`

Comment: What if he want that reverse string returned, not printed?

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac then he would've asked for that, but the OP said `it prints vertically. How do I put the letters horizontally`.